How do I enable linting in PyQGIS modules on MacOS?
I'm running QGIS 3.36 on a MacBook Pro M1.  I would like to work on a processing script, but of course I would like to do this in my IDE (VS Code) not the built-in console.
I have QGIS installed in its own conda env which I built using the following:
conda create -n qgis -c conda-forge qgis geopandas rasterio pysal pdal requests geojson owslib geographiclib
My conda instance is miniconda, located at:
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin/conda
I am able to import qgis.core from the python CLI in Terminal.  I am also able to successfully import classes from qgis.core in VS Code; however, autocomplete/linting does not work with the PyQGIS libraries.  How do I configure it to work?
Curiously, ALL other packages alongside qgis work with VS Code autocomplete/linting right out of the box: pysal, pdal, owslib, geographiclib, geopandas - all of them are recognized right away.

Shortly after posting this, I was poking around and found the answer - however, it is not readily available if you're "new here" so I figured I'd leave an answer for future web searchers.
After activating the qgis environment from Terminal, I started a python prompt and just did the following:
>>import qgis.core
>>qgis.core.__file__

This yielded:
'/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/qgis/share/qgis/python/qgis/core/__init__.py'
So, I went into my VS Code settings JSON, and added this:
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/qgis/share/qgis/python"
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/qgis/share/qgis/python"
    ],
}

After a restart of VS Code, it is now recognizing the qgis.core modules and performing autocomplete and linting.
